# Regx to find the string staring with word and ending either with ?/end of line but not containing a specific word

Tags: regex

Regx to find the string staring with word and ending either with ?/end of line but not containing a specific word

For e.g., I have following URL with different format and want to capture specific part (Page Identifier )

```
Home: https://www.example.com/course/home#/

courseSummary: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/courseSummary?courseName=abc&courceTitle=MyTitle

grounddetails : https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/options/grounddetails

Certification : https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/options/Certification/segment

customer: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/checkout/customer
```

But whenever the 'confirmation' word contain in URL then it SHOULD NOT match.

```
https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/**confirmation**?success=true
```

Could you please help to compose the regex for it

Comment: Which part of the URL you want seems fairly random.  Is there a pattern I'm missing?  Sometimes it's after `/#/` sometimes it's after `/options/`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
^\w+ *: *http(?:s):\/\/(?!.*confirmation).*(?:\?|\n)$
```

[**Regex 101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aRdMLY/1/)

```js
const regex = /^\w+ *: *http(?:s):\/\/(?!.*confirmation).*(?:\?|\n)$/gm;
const str = `Home: https://www.example.com/course/home#/

courseSummary: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/courseSummary?courseName=abc&courceTitle=MyTitle

grounddetails : https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/options/grounddetails

Certification : https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/options/Certification/segment

customer: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/checkout/customer


But whenever the 'confirmation' word contain in URL then it SHOULD NOT match.

blalba: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/**confirmat**?success=true
blalba: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/**confirmation**?success=true
blalba: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/**confirmatio**?success=true
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rizwan, it works.
just want to extend it. Left hand side word is Page Identifier that want catch from the URL if the URL match the pattern
Home: https://www.example.com/course/home#/
courseSummary: https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/courseSummary?courseName=abc&courceTitle=MyTitle
grounddetails : https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/options/grounddetails
Certification : https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/options/Certification/segment
customer:https://www.example.com/tag/mypage/course/#/checkout/customer
SHOULD NOT match when 'confirmation' contain in URL